# How to show the date in DateTimePicker when DataGridView is clicked?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

```vb
If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    TextBox6.Text = row.Cells("ear_number").Value.ToString
    TextBox3.Text = row.Cells("location_of_pig").Value.ToString
    ComboBox3.Text = row.Cells("product_used").Value.ToString
    ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells("reason_for_treatment").Value.ToString
    TextBox4.Text = row.Cells("dose_course_of_treatment").Value.ToString
    TextBox2.Text = row.Cells("person_administering").Value.ToString
    DateTimePicker1.Text = row.Cells("treatment_date").Value.ToString
End If
```

Comment: You didn't specify what the problem is. Do you have some errors?  `DateTimePicker1.Text` is not set  while the other values are? Nothing works? What event handler contains this code?

Comment: I need to display the date in **DateTimePicker1** if I click the **DataGridView**. but I get an error saying: "Value of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for Value. Value should be between MinDate and MaxDate."

Comment: Well, that date cannot be accepted because the DateTimePicker does not support it. [MinDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate) is set to `01/01/1753`.

Comment: I changed the custom format to `yyyy/MM/dd` in vb.net. what else should i do

Comment: It'a not a matter of formatting the DateTime value. A Date of `1/1/0001` cannot be set. The DTP won't accept it. You shouldn't have a Date like that, It usually means that the Date is not correct/not parsed/null (unless you're dealing with historical data :) Also, you shouldn't use DateTime values as strings. You should set the `DateTimePicker.Value` using a DateTime, not the `DateTimePicker.Text` with a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show date in datetimepicker when datagridview is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371311/how-to-show-date-in-datetimepicker-when-datagridview-is-clicked)  Instead of posting this as an additional question, please edit the code segment into your existing question.